Find Expected Value of Larger Claim
The question is the following: Suppose there are two claims that are made on two insured homes, where each claim has pdf
$$f(x) = \frac{4}{x^5}, \qquad 1 < x < \infty$$
Find the expected value of the larger claim:
I let $X_1, X_2$ be the random variables for the two claims, respectively. Letting $Y = \max({X_1,X_2})$, I found $E[Y]$ using the total law of expectation. Specifically,
\begin{align}
E[Y] & = E[Y|X_1 \geq X_2]P(X_1 \geq X_2) + E[Y|X_2 > X_1]P(X_2 \geq X_1) \\
& = E[X_1]P(X_1 \geq X_2) + E[X_2]P(X_2 \geq X_1) \\
& = 2E[X_1]P(X_1 \geq X_2) \qquad  \text{by symmetry}
\end{align}
Calculating, I found:
$$E[X_1]=\int_1^\infty x \cdot \frac{4}{x^5} dx = \frac{4}{3}$$
and
$$P(X_1 \geq X_2) = \int_1^{\infty} \int_1^{x_1} \frac{4}{x_1^5}\frac{4}{x_2^5} dx_2dx_1 = \frac{1}{2}$$
Thus,
$$2E[X_1]P(X_1 \geq X_2)=2\cdot \frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{4}{3}$$
However, the answer is $\dfrac{32}{21}$......Where did my work go wrong?

Your error is in replacing $E[Y|X_1\ge X_2]$ with $E[X_1]$.
It is true that $E[Y|X_1\ge X_2]=E[X_1|X_1\ge X_2]$, but this is
$$
=2\int_1^\infty\int_{x_2}^\infty x_1{4\,dx_1\over x_1^5}{4\,dx_2\over x_2^5} 
={32\over 3}\int_1^\infty {dx_2\over x_2^8}={32\over 21}.
$$

Ah I see. But why is there a $2$ in front.....Wouldn't this cancel with $P(X_1 \geq X_2)$?

The $2$ is $1/P[X_1\ge X_2]$.
